# jQuery parent element problem

Tags: jquery, parent

In an attempt to target a specific div, I am using the following code:

```
function popupBox($area){
        //$mainBox  =   $(document).createElement('div').attr('id', 'mainBox');
        $mainBox    =   $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'mainBox');
        $($mainBox).text('main box responding');

        $parent =   $('div#custom-page-node-block-output-right div.views-row').parent( $($area) );
        $($parent).addClass('parent');
```

}

The only issue is there are 2 divs with the class **div#custom-page-node-block-output-right div.views-row**.
I though since the source element whose parent I am looking for is within one of the two divs, I should only get a single element in response but it's returning both.

You can see the issue in action at http://test5omniforce.co.uk/node/3 (best viewed in Firefox). Just hover your mouse over any of the blue-colored rooms on either floor plan.

The idea is to get a green background over the immediate parent of any room over which the mouse is hovering but I get both. It's obviously because I am using classes instead of IDs but I can't use IDs in this solution.

Can anyone advice if there is a way to achieve the desired effect with adjustments to my code?

Thanks

Comment: ID's in jQuery must be unique for your information, if you set 2 items with the same class name and give them a id of 1 and 2 this will make them unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$('div#custom-page-node-block-output-right div.views-row').parent( $($area) ).first();
```

or:

```
$('div#custom-page-node-block-output-right div.views-row').parent( $($area) ).last();
```

One or the other might work but I agree with John, the id's should be unique.

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/nxGjA/2/

Comment: Updated my answer to use more of the code in the question and added a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Thanks John and Jen. I agree with you, IDs must be unique. It's the reason why I can't use IDs in this solution because the site generates the divs and my code dynamically searches through them. If I used IDs, I will have to write separate code for each div - not very dynamic

Answer (score 1):

```
$parent = $($area).parents('div.views-row');
$parent.addClass('parent');
```

Note: if the element is a jQuery element (like $parent is, since it is returned from a jQuery call,) you do not have to wrap it in *$()*. Also note that $area is not a jQuery object, just a passed in HTML element.

Comment: $area is any element passed in from another function. So, I just wrap it in jQuery when I start looking for it's parent